# Transferred file from UNIX server to PC with Filezilla, there's no line breaks in file

Tags: excel, unix, ftp, filezilla

I'm using Filezilla to copy files from a UNIX server. Afterwards, I'm using Notepad to open this file, the content is there but there are no line breaks. I have to copy the content into Excel so having no line breaks is a pain.

I've tried using the **ASCII** and the **binary** transfer method in Filezilla's settings but its not working.

I'v tried using Notepad++ to open it but to no avail. Even changing Filezilla to WinSCP makes no difference and I even tried the various encodings.

I don't dare to change any settings in the UNIX server because it is being used by hundreds of employees in my company and I'm afraid any changes might break it. For years, the employees here have been using the command prompt which is extremely not user-friendly to copy out the files' contents into Excel.

I'm trying to find an easier way but so far I'm stuck here.

**Edit**: The file looks like this when opened in Notepad++. I have uploaded a screenshot.

[image: The file looks like this when opened in Notepad++]

Comment: This seems like a XY problem. Can you try to explain further what you originally want to solve?

Comment: @M.Becerra there are actually line breaks in the Unix file, but somehow when it is transferred to windows, Notepad was unable to apply the line breaks

Comment: Please move your question to [su] (delete here, re-post there). It's [off-topic here](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Moderators can migrate the question automatically if you flag the post as off-topic

Comment: @MechMK1 Well, of course, I did flag it off-topic. But why waste moderators' time, if the OP can do it. And OP should also be educated to learn the scope of the SE sites.

Comment: @MartinPrikryl Because I already wrote an extensive answer for OPs problem. Migrating the question would migrate the answer to as far as I know, and I'd hate for a good answer to go to waste

Comment: @MartinPrikryl shall I delete this post and move it to Super User?

Comment: Imo, you should. Notify @MechMK1 about the move (just before you delete the question), so the he can repost his answer there.

Answer (score 0):

## Why is this happening?

There are linebreaks, but Windows' Notepad only recognizes DOS-style linebreaks, not UNIX-style linebreaks.

[This Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) explains the different newline styles common across operating systems.

> - `LF` (Linefeed) is used by Unix and Unix-like systems.
> - `CR+LF` (Carriage Return   Linefeed) is used by Windows and MS-DOS, as well as some other systems.

This means when you create a file on a Unix-System, it'll look like this:

[image: Unix-style newlines]

While on Windows, the same file would look like this:

[image: Windows-style newlines]

Notepad in its simplicity expects to only ever encounter files with "proper" Windows-style Newlines, so if the `CR` symbol is missing, it does not interpret it as newline.

---

## What can you do now?

### 1. Get a better editor

The easiest way would be to use [Notepad++](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/), which I used for these screenshots, or any other more sophisticated text editor. Notepad++ understands both styles of newlines and even displays them in the status bar or allows you to convert between those via `Edit -> EOL Conversion -> Windows (CR LF)`

### 2. Convert before you download

The tool [`unix2dos`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix2dos) allows you to easily convert between Unix- and DOS-style newlines. Keep in mind that the default behaviour is to **overwrite the file**, so by calling `unix2dos foo.txt`, the file foo.txt will now be converted to DOS-style newlines. Use `unix2dos -n foo.txt foo.dos.txt` to create a new file called foo.dos.txt with DOS-style lineendings.

Please note that the Wikipedia entry of `unix2dos` mentions a vast array of alternatives you could use instead, just in case you cannot install new software on your system.

Comment: when I view my files on NotePad++, i'm seeing the word NULL instead of LF. Is this a format problem in the server and not related to a conversion problem? I have edited my post to include a screenshot of this.

Comment: @user107257 Are you sure that this does not occur on the unix system as well; in other words: Are you sure it is the file transfer that adds these `NUL` characters? Use a tool to create a hash sum (sha1, sha256, etc) and see if they are equal on windows and unix.